# Hive query going in skew while writing below join:

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
Select a.drr1,b.drr1 from a left join b on a.drr1=b.drr1
```

Here in table `a` has duplicate `drr1` values, while table `b` has unique `drr1` value. It's a Many to One join in hive.

Since tables a is very large and duplicates value are many, it taking too long.
Any pointers on how this can be tackled in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.drr1=B.drr1;
```